# What is the exact dimensions of a monospaced character bounding box(courier new specifically), and how would I find it on a per image basis in Python?

Tags: python, ascii-art, monospace

I know that all characters in a monospaced font like Courier New have bounding boxes of the exact same size. An * and a ] both have bounding boxes of same sizes, however, each of these characters fill up different amounts of 'space' within the bounding box, since an * is made up of fewer pixels than a ]

The bounding box in question can be viewed if I highlight a single character with my mouse, the blue tall rectangular box. What is the exact dimension of this box in pixels, and does this box have any actual name?

I wanted to make a Python program to generate ascii art which needs to know the dimension of this box, essentially I want to scan thru a regular non-text/non-ascii image, in these bounding box size increments one by one, finding and storing the average color value within each of the bounding boxes in the image somewhere else

However I realized that depending on the image size itself, the size of the 'bounding box' sized increments would also have to be different for each image. How would I go about 1) finding the dimensions of the bounding box of a Courier New character 2) decide how big it should be on a per image basis?

Comment: Where did you learn this "fact" about ASCII characters & bounding boxes?

Comment: @ScottHunter I assumed the best way to find the average color value of an image in a character sized bounding box portion of the image, would be to scan through the image with a bounding box which I assumed every character would be using

I did have trouble figuring out what exactly the bounding box would be, but when higlighting a bunch of ascii characters one by one like a ] or a * I noticed the highlighting blue rectangle is the same size regardless of the character

Comment: You are confusing [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) with [Monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) of which there are many, and it's impossible to know which one you mean in the question. I would recommend doing a bit more research and if you still have issues - coming back to ask a better question

Comment: @AlmogAtNailo Very sorry, I did mean monospaced fonts. The testing of the boxes I did was done on Courier New font to be specific. I will soon edit my question to make it reflect the same

Comment: You need to choose a graphics package with font support, and it will provide some method to get the extents of a string. For example, [`tkinter.font.Font.measure()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.font.html) or [`wx.DC.GetTextExtent()`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.DC.html#wx.DC.GetTextExtent). Then maybe try a couple of different single-character strings just to make sure they're really the same size.

Comment: NB. these are usually called _extents_. Fonts are usually 2-dimensional, so inspecting the dimension isn't likely to be useful.